# How to prove that $x\cdot y\neq 0$ when $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq0$ via field axioms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

How to prove that $x\cdot y\neq 0$ when $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq0$ via field axioms?

According to the field axioms, especially the Commutativity of multiplication it is $a\cdot b=b\cdot a$. Is that enough to disprove $x\cdot y=0$ hence proving that $x\cdot y\neq 0$

Comment: Thank you for your response. To what "definition" are you reffering? To the aforementioned Commutativity?

Comment: Sorry, in my definition of a field it's so that $F\setminus \{0\}$ is an Abelian group with respect to multiplication. You must have some other one.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $x\cdot y=0$ and $x\neq 0$, then $\frac1x$ exists and $\frac1x\cdot x\cdot y=\frac1x\cdot 0$, what is equivalent to $y=0$.

Comment: I have to prove: x·y=0  ⇔  (x=0)∨(y=0). I have already proven  (x=0)∨(y=0) ⇒ x·y=0. But now I have to prove  x·y=0 ⇒ (x=0)∨(y=0). And I decided to do it via Contraposition, thus x≠0 ∧ y≠0 ⇒ x·y≠0. But how am I going to do that?

Comment: Yeah, but since it is $\Longleftrightarrow$ I also have to prove that $(x=0)\vee (y=0) \Longrightarrow x\cdot y=0$.

Comment: @Analysis ok, I understand... Just use the above. I had proven it in my answer, I just skipped the part that $\frac1x\cdot 0=0$

Comment: I want to start like that: Suppose that $x\cdot y=0$ with $y\neq 0$ and $x\neq 0$ ..... and than disprove that statement

Comment: @Analysis suppose you start like you want... Then from my answer you get the contradiction that $y=0$, then it is not possible that $x\cdot y=0$ and $x,y\neq 0$ at once, so if $x\cdot y=0$ then $x,y\neq 0$ must be false.

Comment: @analysis both answers given so far do the same thing and correctly prove what you are asking for via proof by contradiction.  Showing that $xy=0$ and $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ is impossible to all occur simultaneously by showing the first two conditions imply that $y=0$, contradicting the third condition.  This all is equivalent to showing that $x$ and $y$ both being nonzero implies their product is nonzero.

Comment: the logic negation of $x=0$ and $y=0$ is $$\lnot((x=0)\land (x=0))\iff \lnot(x=0)\lor\lnot (y=0)\iff (x\neq 0)\lor (y\neq 0)$$

Comment: Is a proof even necessary though? According to the field axioms, especially the Commutativity of multiplication it is a⋅b=b⋅a. Is that enough to disprove x⋅y=0 hence proving that x⋅y≠0

Comment: @Analysis I dont follow you, but commutativity alone, as the unique axiom to be used, is not enough to prove what the exercise asks. There are a lot of algebraic structures that have a commutative operation and are not fields, neither have the property to be proved here.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\neq0$, then it as an inverse. So$$y=1.y=(x^{-1}.x).y=x^{-1}.(x.y)=x^{-1}.0=0.$$Now, it remains to be proved from the field axioms that you always have $x.0=0$.

Comment: I have already proved $x\cdot 0=0$ and $-x=(-1)x$. Now I have to prove that $x\cdot y=0 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad (x=0)\vee (y=0)$. Proof by cases: I have proven the cases $x\neq 0$ and $y=0$ and vice versa. Now the third case $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$

Comment: Since you have already proved that you always have $x.0=0$, there is nothing else that you need to prove. The fact that you always have $x.0=0$was all that was needed to complete my proof of the fact that $x\neq0\implies y=0$.